# Input function help (python)

Tags: python

I was trying to play around with the input function. However, it seems that this code is not correct, I looked to see examples online but they tend to be basic and what i was trying to do was slightly above basic. Also, is it possible to put the return function instead of the print one? if not why? I'm new to this so if these all sound stupid please forgive me.

cheers!

```
def user_data(x):   
    age = input("how old are you?")
    if age == 20:
        print("you win")
    else:
        print("you lose")
```

Comment: COnvert to int `int(input("how old are you?"))`

Comment: input() ==  string --- so:  `if age == "20":` - or convert it to an integer - but then you need to handle smartass inputs like "twentytwo" (as string, not number) to stop your app from crashing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: @James lol - found my own comment on that question.

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string, while you are comparing `age` (a string) to an integer.

You have to either compare `age` to a string (so `age == "20"`), or convert `age` to an `int` (so `int(age) == 20`).

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to find out how `input` works.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def user_data(age):
    if age == 20:
        print("you win")
    else:
        print("you lose")

age = int(input("how old are you?")) 
user_data(age)
```

Comment: line 2: change `age` to `x` if you want it to use the parameter you pass in.

Comment: This gives me "you win" all the time regardless of which number i put

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.